# What's the point of XamlType.GetAliasedProperty

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've tried looking for information about this method and I'm unable to understand what's the meaning and utility of it.

This is what MSDN says about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/vstudio/system.xaml.xamltype.getaliasedproperty(v=vs.100).aspx

Can someone explain what does it do, in other words? Some example?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could imagine, buttonXamlType.GetAliasedProperty(XamlLanguage.Name) would return a XamlMember for FrameworkElement.Name. This means that x:Name and Name, when used on a button, are aliased, or synonymous. Defined by     [RuntimeNamePropertyAttribute("Name")] decoration on FrameworkElement class.

Asking buttonXamlType.GetAliasedProperty(XamlLanguage.Lang) would return a XamlMember for FrameworkElement.Language, as the [XmlLangProperty("Language")] attribute is on the FrameworkElement class.

-Rob Relyea, PM/Architect for System.Xaml.dll

Comment: There's nothing like listening to the master on the topic. Thanks, Rob! Excellent explanation!